# How to use connect() and withStyles() for class component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

How to use connect() and withStyles() for class component in React?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({...});
const styles = useStyles();

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    ...

    render() {
      return(<div className={...}>Stackoverflow</div>)
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({...});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(withStyles(styles)(MyComponent))
```

Comment: have you used redux-thunk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use compose as well

```
import { bindActionCreators, compose } from 'redux';

export default compose(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps, // or put null here if you do not have actions to dispatch
  ),
  withStyles(styles),
)(YourComponent);
```

Comment: i have a new problem

Comment: What seems to be the new problem?

Comment: added in question

Comment: the problem that you have added is very different from the one that is in the title of your question. It seems to me that you are trying to dispatch a function without having mapDispatchToProps inside your component. If my answer solved the question you had with connect, I suggest you mark it as resolved and open new question with dispatch error